# Save Python Byte object value as String

Tags: python

Input:

```
'hello '.encode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
b'hello \xf0\x9f\x93\x8c'
```

Output I want:

```
"hello \xf0\x9f\x93\x8c"
```

I need this to pass it to the "Content-Disposition" header parameter for UTF-8 filename download.
file response is Stream.

Comment: Show the code and the error message you get, when using the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert bytes to string with the exact same code values, you should decode it in ISO-8859-1 (or Latin1 which is an alias and simpler to remember):

```
print(repr('hello '.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')))
```

gives `'hello ð\x9f\x93\x8c'`